# Regexp to match Captial cases in address Pattern

Tags: regex, alteryx

I want a regular expression to find addresses having mixed characters that can be used in Alteryx.
The first example has capital cases in the beginning and second one in between.

1. IFBDAGE,Place des Augustins 19,Bonita Springs
2. 28/10 Macquarie Street,NEWSTEAD,Bonita Springs

Comment: I could get first capital cases using \b[A-Z0-9]{2,}\b, but not sure how to find in between the string

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it with regular expressions. Make your life easier and use a normal function:

```
public static string GetUpperCasePart(string address, char delimiter)
{
    foreach (var part in address.Split(delimiter))
    {
        if (part.All(c => Char.IsLetter(c) && Char.IsUpper(c)))
            return part;
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/x3NxOJ

Comment: Can we do run this as stored procedure in SQL? I have the addresses in one column..

Answer (score 0):

In your regex `\b[A-Z0-9]{2,}\b` why are you using `0-9`, if you just use `\b[A-Z]{2,}\b`, it will give the capital letters in the middle as well.

Comment: This works....But it will also return the addresses with full caps...I want only the ones with Mixed cases.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your Strings ***don´t*** contain the capitals in upperCase, matching should be difficult... Otherwise, Abbondanza´s solution is working and you can use the RegEx like Anita explained ;)